# QgsExpression cannot get expected result when there is "\" in the string

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select-by-attribute

I hope to use `QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression)` to get desired features.

The statement in QgsExpression is:

```py
expr = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("\"planid\" in (48757) AND spi like '0\\%'")
```

The feature has `"planid" = 48757`, and `"spi"` field is string like `'0\abcdefg'` .

So I intended to match `'0\\'` in the `QgsExpression`, but it didn't work at all. I got nothing returned.

If I changed the string to `"\"planid\" in (48757) AND spi like '0%'"` by removing `'\\'`, then it could return a feature.

But I really need `'\\'`, since it's a very important character.

So how should I modify the string to make it work?

**UPDATE:**

From @MatthiasKuhn suggestion, I tested to use '\\\\' in QgsExpression,  like `"\"planid\" in (48757) AND spi like '0\\\\%'"`.

It didn't work from Python scripts, but I did get a hint from it. After running the statement from "Select by Expression" in QGIS, four '\' worked fine. So this is the correct format.

Therefore, I built the statement in Python with 8 '\', and it did work.

`expr = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("\"planid\" in (48757) AND spi like '0\\\\\\\\%'")`

I understand why Python needs to double the number of '\', but can @MatthiasKuhn or anyone else explain why I need four '\' here in QGIS?

Comment: Did you try to double up the \ in the like part to `0\\\\%` ?

Comment: Hi @MatthiasKuhn, I tried ```0\\\\% and  0\\\% and  0\\% and  0\%``` . None of them worked.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasKuhn, I updated my question. Can you tell me why there is four '\' here. And could you answer the question instead of comment, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Escape character

A `\` stands for an escape character in many contexts and changes the meaning of the following character. E.g. `\n` often means newline, `\t` tab. To actually write the `\` itself. To actually make us of a `\` it has to be escaped itself to `\\`.

This is for example the case for a LIKE operator which uses a regular expression engine which needs `\` escape. Double the backslash `\\`.
However, before it arrives in the regular expression, it also traverses the QGIS expression parser where it needs to be escaped too. Double it `\\\\`.
However, since you are using python to create this, python already needs to escape things. Which means escaping each single `\` again. Double it `\\\\\\\\`.